# for loop produces unexpected result in Python

Tags: loops, python-3.7

I'm struggling with this 'simple' code. I have the following list of objects:

```
[
{
    "element_id": "6185316",
    "id": 123456,
    "inv_part_id": 2345250,
    "is_spare": true,
    "num_sets": 191,
    "part": {
        "external_ids": {
            "BrickOwl": [
                "359273"
            ],
            "NODEX": [
                "17715",
                "19385"
            ]
        },
        "name": "Bar 3L",
        "part_cat_id": 32,
        "part_num": "27808",
        "print_of": null
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "set_num": "71043-1"
},
{
    "element_id": "6185316",
    "id": 654321,
    "inv_part_id": 2345250,
    "is_spare": true,
    "num_sets": 191,
    "part": {
        "external_ids": {
            "BrickOwl": [
                "359273"
            ],
            "NODEX": [
                "17715",
                "19385"
            ]
        },
        "name": "Bar 3L",
        "part_cat_id": 32,
        "part_num": "5861",
        "print_of": null
    },
    "quantity": 1,
    "set_num": "71043-1"
}]
```

My goal is to just add the value of part_num (inside PART object) to a list. I'm using the following for this:

```
    final = []
    count = 1
    for x in spf: 
        for y in x["part"]["part_num"]:
            final.append(y)
```

but it is appending each char instead of adding the complete value:

```
['2', '7', '8', '0', '8', '5', '8', '6', '1']
```

The expected output should be:

```
['27808', '5861']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can just do final.append(x["part"]["part_num"]). No need for the second for loop.

Comment: @Kay you are correct. That worked!. thanks..